# How to display a counter in a window and make it close?

Tags: javascript

I have this code in which when clicking a button a window opens and a counter appears that is a random number between 1 and 100, this counts up to 0 and the window closes, but I don't know very well what I'm doing wrong since nothing appears in the window that I open. Here I leave part of the html code because I decide to open it by giving a button and the javascript.

```js
var ventana;

function abrir() {
  ventana = window.open("", "new_window", "width=800,height=500,status=no,toolbar=no,menubar=no");
}

window.onload = contar;

function contar() {
  var contartiempo = Math.floor(Math.random() * 100);
  ventana.document.getElementById('contador').innerHTML = contartiempo;
  if (contartiempo == 0) {
    ventana.close();
  }
  ventana.document.write(" tu contador:<span id = contador></span>") //quiero que se muestre en la ventana abierta el contador
}
```

```html
<body>
  <input type="submit" value="Abrir" onclick="abrir()">
</body>
```

Comment: If you take a look at the error being produced from your code "ventana is undefined" that should give you an idea. You don't assign anything to that variable until _after_ the button has been clicked but your code is expecting it to have a value immediately the window loads.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, there are a lot of concern in this code:

1. You're loading `contar` function on load and till that time ventana is `undefined` hence you'll get an error when you do something like `ventana.whatever` (trying to access a property on undefined).
2. Since the document in the new page has no span with `id = contador` when created, the line `ventana.document.getElementById('contador').innerHTML = contartiempo;` will also fail.

To fix it:

```js
var ventana;

function abrir() {
  ventana = window.open("", "new_window", "width=800,height=500,status=no,toolbar=no,menubar=no");

  contar()
}

function contar() {
  if (ventana) {
    var contartiempo = Math.floor(Math.random() * 100);
    ventana.document.write(" tu contador:<span id = contador></span>") //quiero que se muestre en la ventana abierta el contador
    ventana.document.getElementById('contador').innerHTML = contartiempo;
    if (contartiempo == 0) {
      ventana.close();
    }
    
  }
}
```

Here I am calling `contar` function on click of the button in parent document after we have opened the new window. Then I am putting the span & the other layout on the page with `ventana.document.write`. Then we are adding an `innerHTML` to that `span`.

HTML part will require no changes.

Answer (score 0):

I have already solved my problem, the code shows a window, performs the counter and closes that window, here the result

```
var ventana;

function abrir() {
  ventana = window.open("", "new_window", "width=800,height=500,status=no,toolbar=no,menubar=no");

  contar()
}
window.onload = contar//para que cuando 
var contartiempo = Math.floor(Math.random() * 100);
function contar() {
  if (ventana) {

    ventana.document.write(" <span id = contador></span>") //quiero que se muestre en la ventana abierta el contador
    ventana.document.getElementById('contador').innerHTML = contartiempo;
    if (contartiempo == 0) {
      ventana.close();
    } else{
        contartiempo-=1;
        setTimeout("contar()",1000);
    }
    
  }
}
```